# Thunderbird not showing notifications for incoming mail

Tags: thunderbird, notification

Thunderbird 78.7.1 (apt version) running on Ubuntu 20.10 with default Gnome desktop.
I don't get pop-up notifications when new mail arrives, although I believe I configured it properly.
Thunderbird is running, minimized, and Birdtray shows new mail items, but no pop-up notifications. I do get pop-ups from Gmail in Firefox, so notifications are working on my system, but not from TB.
See screenshots.
[image]
[image]

Comment: I wonder if you could select play a custom sound file, and use the inotifywait (install it) command to look for that sound files access and then trigger a notification using  ... notify-send "you have mail " -t 1000   ....  that wont have any useful information as to what the email is about,  but it will notify of new mail. you might also uses inotifywait to look for changes to thunderbirds inbox files.... see https://linuxadmin.io/using-inotifywait-to-monitor-a-directory-and-move-files-to-another-directory/  which includes access as a trigger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install `thunderbird-gnome-support`

```
sudo apt install thunderbird-gnome-support
```

Now Thunderbird notifications integrate well with Gnome desktop and Gnome notification center.